How create multiples files using a text file as template and dataframe
I need to create multiple files that will be Python functions using a text file as a template, my template will contain something like:
mytemplate.txt

#text as template to python file
def D_{var_1}_O(pref, in_params):
    logger.info(f"{pref} Transform params: {in_params}")
    table_name = '{var_1}'
    load = table_info['TIPO_CARGA']
    query = 'select {list just NVARCHAR2 column with coma separator} from {var_1}'
    logger.info(f"Query: {query}")
    return query

The idea is use this template to create several Python files that will contain one function per table. And there is a JSON that I will use as a source to create the the Oython files
the JSON is something like:
{
    "schema": {
        "CUENTA_C": {
            "TIPO_CARGA": "daily",
            "FIELDS": {
                "ID": "NVARCHAR2",
                "DATE": "DATE",
                "ISOPEN": "NUMBER",
                "NAME": "NVARCHAR2",
                "DEA": "NVARCHAR2"
            }
        },
        "BUSINESS__C": {
            "TIPO_CARGA": "daily",
            "FIELDS": {
                "ID": "NVARCHAR2",
                "ISOPEN": "NUMBER",
                "NAME": "NVARCHAR2",
                "CURRENCY": "NVARCHAR2"
            }
        },
        "LLAMADAS__C": {
            "TIPO_CARGA": "daily",
            "FIELDS": {
                "ID": "NVARCHAR2",
                "OWNERID": "NVARCHAR2",
                "ISOPEN": "NUMBER",
                "ZIP": "NVARCHAR2",
                "COUNTRY": "NVARCHAR2"
            }
        }
    }
}

So the result (ONE of the python files) must be something like this:
cuenta_c.py

def D_CUENTA_C_O(pref, in_params):
    logger.info(f"{pref} Transform params: {in_params}")
    table_name = 'CUENTA_C'
    load = table_info['TIPO_CARGA']
    query = 'select ID, NAME, DEA from CUENTA_C'
    logger.info(f"Query: {query}")
    return query

Can somebody give me a hand to resolve this challenge?

I feel like creating a python file dynamically is a bit of a security vulnerability. what if instead you create a dictionary that holds dynamically created python functions?

Isn't it just a matter of looping through the JSON and writing a text file with a .py extension? Is that the root of your question? If not, what do you have so far and what isn't working?

I am not completely clear about your use case, but I think using a template .txt file to dynamically generate python code is risky because the txt file is external to the python code and therefore vulnerable to code injection. Someone could modify the txt file template and create python files to do whatever they want.
You can accomplish something similar by directly using the template logic in your python code, and storing dynamically generated functions in a dictionary, and this would be much safer because everything is contained in one python file.
I would probably do something like the following:
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) 

class FunctionManager:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._all_functions = {}
    
    def add_functions(self, json_data):
        """Iterate through json_data and create all functions dynamically"""

        function_info = json_data["schema"]
        for name, info in function_info.items():
            function_name = f"D_{name}_O"
            all_fields = list(info['FIELDS'].keys())
            select_fields = [field for field in all_fields if field not in ["DATE","ISOPEN"]]
            query_fields = ",".join(select_fields)

            def dynamic_function(pref, in_params, query_fields=query_fields, name=name):
                logger.info(f"{pref} Transform params: {in_params}")

                # commented out because I don't know what table_info is 
                # load = table_info['TIPO_CARGA']

                query = f'select {query_fields} from {name}'
                logger.info(f"Query: {query}")
                return query

            self._all_functions[function_name] = dynamic_function
    
    def get_function(self, function_name):
        """Retrieve a function by its name"""

        return self._all_functions.get(function_name)

You could instantiate and use FunctionManager class as follows:
function_manager = FunctionManager()

json_sample = {
    "schema": {
        "CUENTA_C": {
            "TIPO_CARGA": "daily",
            "FIELDS": {
                "ID": "NVARCHAR2",
                "DATE": "DATE",
                "ISOPEN": "NUMBER",
                "NAME": "NVARCHAR2",
                "DEA": "NVARCHAR2"
            }
        },
        "BUSINESS__C": {
            "TIPO_CARGA": "daily",
            "FIELDS": {
                "ID": "NVARCHAR2",
                "ISOPEN": "NUMBER",
                "NAME": "NVARCHAR2",
                "CURRENCY": "NVARCHAR2"
            }
        },
        "LLAMADAS__C": {
            "TIPO_CARGA": "daily",
            "FIELDS": {
                "ID": "NVARCHAR2",
                "OWNERID": "NVARCHAR2",
                "ISOPEN": "NUMBER",
                "ZIP": "NVARCHAR2",
                "COUNTRY": "NVARCHAR2"
            }
        }
    }
}

function_manager.add_functions(json_sample)

Then retrieve and use your functions as needed:
D_CUENTA_C_O = function_manager.get_function('D_CUENTA_C_O')
D_BUSINESS__C_O = function_manager.get_function('D_BUSINESS__C_O')
D_LLAMADAS__C_O = function_manager.get_function('D_LLAMADAS__C_O')

print(D_CUENTA_C_O("test1","test2"))
print(D_BUSINESS__C_O("test1","test2"))
print(D_LLAMADAS__C_O("test1","test2"))

Output:
select ID,NAME,DEA from CUENTA_C
select ID,NAME,CURRENCY from BUSINESS__C
select ID,OWNERID,ZIP,COUNTRY from LLAMADAS__C

